# How do I write output of a command to multiple text files where the file names are based on part of the command output?

Tags: linux, command-line

I have a command that outputs a few lines of text to the console in this format: `<FILE_NAME>: <STRING_VALUE>`.
Example:

```
FILE1: abc1
FILE2: def2
FILE3: ghi3
```

I want to create files, FILE1,FILE2 and FILE3 with the contents of abc1,def2 and ghi3 respectively.

Something like

```
echo "text" >> FILE1
```

but have it do recursively

What is a single one-liner command to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "do it recursively" in the edit?

Comment: @tink Oh, I thought I add in a bit more detail. What I meant was doing echo "text" >> FILE1 but on multiple lines of output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pipe your command to awk:

```
command | awk -F ': *' '{print $2 > $1}'
```

We define the **field separator** to be `F ': *'` (colon followed by any number of spaces).

We print the second field of each row and redirect it to the value of the first field.

```
$ ls
FILE1  FILE2  FILE3
$ cat FILE*
abc1
def2
ghi3
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome.  And I just saw the edit in your question; you can, of course, also use the `>>` in awk ...